# Wpf PasswordBox must show characters when I click CheckBox

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="300">
    <PasswordBox x:Name="PasswordBox1" Height="30" PasswordChar="*" Password="12345"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox1" Content="Show Password"/>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

vb.net

```
Class MainWindow 
Private Sub CheckBox1_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.Checked
    PasswordBox1.PasswordChar = CChar("")
End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox1_Unchecked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.Unchecked
    PasswordBox1.PasswordChar = CChar("*")
End Sub
End Class
```

Run the above codes and click CheckBox1 in order to understand what is happening.

How can PasswordBox show characters which are **12345** when I click CheckBox?

So, following line need to be repaired.

> PasswordBox1.PasswordChar = CChar(" ")

Comment: The examples on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.passwordbox.passwordrevealmode#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_PasswordBox_PasswordRevealMode) may help you.

Comment: The link you have posted is about UWP now WPF...

Answer (score 0):

This will work for what you are looking for although it will expose your passwords in memory. We have a textbox and a password box in the same place on our UI and when the user checks the Show Password checkbox we collapse the passwordbox and show the hidden textbox, at the same time updating the text. You will need to check you are using the password from the visible ui control when you send the password.

Xaml code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Grid Width="300" Height="40">
    <PasswordBox Name="passwordBox" PasswordChar="*" />
    <TextBox Name="passwordTxtBox" Visibility="Collapsed" />
  </Grid>
<CheckBox Margin="10" Name="showPassword" Unchecked="ShowPassword_Unchecked"  Checked="ShowPassword_Checked" />
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
    private void ShowPassword_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        passwordTxtBox.Text = passwordBox.Password;
        passwordBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        passwordTxtBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void ShowPassword_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        passwordBox.Password = passwordTxtBox.Text;
        passwordTxtBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        passwordBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Comment: There is a solution using only one TextBox... But my question is about PasswordBox... So, your answer is not related to my question. But anyway thanks for your effort...

Comment: Yes but I don't believe it is possible to make an WPF password box show the text in the clear, so this is a possible workaround another would be to create your own passwordbox control.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Using MahApps.Metro ... after installing it from nuget.org ... you must import it in the head of your xaml like this xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winf/xaml/controls"

and then ... just use it's style for your PasswordBox control

```
<PasswordBox  Style="{StaticResource MetroButtonRevealedPasswordBox}" />
```

you can even change the content for the show icon using the controls:PasswordBoxHelper.RevealButtonContent attached property

Comment: paste this line in your package Manager console ...



Install-Package MahApps.Metro     ....



then using it in your .xaml as written above

xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winf/xaml/controls" 
this is quick start to use:
https://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html

Comment: Doesn't work for me, it breaks http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity thank you